# How could I get a direct child element within JavaScript (without using jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

Within the following code, I am trying to get all `.node` elements that are direct child elements of `.row` elements. Currently my code will look for any given element that matches the `.node` class within `.row` element.

How could I get the direct node (e.g. in CSS this would look something like this: `.row > .node`) in plain JavaScript?

```js
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
var nodes = [];

for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  console.log(rows[i].getElementsByClassName("node"));
}
```

```css
.node {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.node,
.empty {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="node">
    Foo
  </div>
  <div class="node d-none">
    Foo
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="empty">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="node d-none">
      Foo
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the final `.node` element (which is nested in like so: `.row > .row > .node`) will be called for multiple times because I am not addressing it as direct child.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971668/javascript-get-all-direct-children#34971678) which explains the use of `document.querySelector`. Should I be using that for the purpose I am trying to reach here? Or Could I achieve the same by just using `document.getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: This repo shows some examples of js code without jquery. There's a section for querySelector https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery#query-selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `querySelectorAll` and use the query string `.row > .node`:

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".row > .node");
nodes.forEach(node => console.log(node.textContent));
```

```css
.node {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.node,
.empty {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="node">
    Foo
  </div>
  <div class="node d-none">
    Foo
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="empty">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="node d-none">
      Foo
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In almost all cases, a selector string that works to select elements in jQuery will work to select elements with `querySelectorAll` as well (and to select elements with CSS). (There are a few rare exceptions like `:contains`, which only have meaning in jQuery.)

Note that you need to use

```
.row > .node
```

not

```
.row < .node
```

to select `.node`s which are children of a `.row`.

Comment: Does `document.querySelectorAll` return the same as what I described above? And a bit off-topic, but what benefit other than readability does the `.forEach` has? Is it working the same as my loop, or even better?

Comment: As one paste puts it: Loops fail to clearly signal the intention of your code, and as such should be avoided whenever possible (prefer higher-order functions, such as .map, .reduce, .filter, ...). See also: http://qr.ae/RNMEGA and https://gist.github.com/robotlolita/7643014 Code readability is possibly the *most important thing* to optimize for when writing code, in most situations (IMO), so I always avoid `for` loops when possible, they're verbose, require manual iteration, have no built-in abstraction, and aren't composable.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, which is an array-like object (and has the `forEach` method), but it's not exactly the same thing as an array. If you want to transform it into an array, you can spread it: `[...document.querySelectorAll(..)]`

Comment: So if I understand it correctly: if I would like to get a single element within a HTML collection (e.g. by using `document.getElementsByClassName`), it would not be a correct way to use a loop to get this job done? Would you address that situation with above given example? Or would that be a different matter? (Am just asking this out of curiosity)

Comment: Problems with the `getElementsBy` methods are that (1) they're inflexible (in comparison to the ability to use a query string, as you can see with `querySelectorAll`) and (2) they're *live* collections - they may mutate *while you're iterating over them*! This is very unintuitive and is a frequent source of bugs.

Comment: If you used `getElementsByClassName` to achieve your goal here, you would have to specify that the `.node` you want is a direct child of the current `.row` being iterated over - perhaps call `querySelector` on the `.row`, or (worse idea) turn the `.children` of the `.row` into an array and then use `.find` to find a child which is a `.node`.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('.row > .node')`
The selector parameter in querySelector function is the same with CSS/JQuery